# Values of process.exitValue() in JAVA

Tags: java, process

This question is about the values of ***process.exitValue()***.

If ***process.exitValue()***=*0* its ok, if it's *-1* something is wrong, but if it's something else, what does it mean?
For instance i am taking **6**. That is the code i use:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
process.waitFor();  
Integer result = process.exitValue();
```

**Edit:** if process hangs, than ***process.exitValue()*** = 6

Comment: It depends on the command!

Comment: See your commands exit codes for more details

Comment: It is the subprocess that determines its exit value. You must read its documentation.

Answer (score 4):

That's up to the process in question. Even the "0 means success" is a convention more than anything else - although it's a *very* common one.

In general I would assume that any non-zero value is an error of some description; look at the documentation for whatever process you're executing for the meaning of specific exit values. If you don't know as the developer what process you're executing (e.g. it's user-specified) then there's no general way of interpreting a non-zero exit code other than "failure".

Answer (score 0):

it depends entirely on what the command is doing see the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()